# Stop server program inside a threading module python

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

I'm writing a simple information server in python that replies to 3 different commands. I must handle multiple clients using the threading module, so any other method of handling multiple clients won't do. Whenever a clients sends 'EXIT' to the server, the server program should quit executing. I thought I could accomplish this by closing the connection and the socket inside the thread that handles a client. When I do this the server just keeps running after receiving the 'EXIT' and it crashes when the next client tries to connect, with the following error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 530, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 483, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "info_mult_thread.py", line 69, in handle_client
    s.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 222, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
error: [Errno 57] Socket is not connected
```

Here is my code:

```
import socket
import time

from threading import Thread

TCP_HOST = 'localhost'
TCP_PORT = 1997
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024


# create socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

# bind the socket to the server
s.bind((TCP_HOST, TCP_PORT))

# put socket into server mode, this means listen for incoming connections
s.listen(10)


def handle_client(connection_input, client_address_input):
    """ Will handle the requests of the client
    :param connection_input: Connection with the client
    :param client_address_input: Address of the client
    :return: No return value
    """
    complete_command = False
    command = ""

    while True:
        # wait 10 seconds for data from client, otherwise disconnect
        connection_input.settimeout(10.0)

        try:
            data = connection_input.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)

        except socket.timeout:
                # client is idle, close the connection
                connection_input.close()
                break

        else:
            # client has closed the connection
            if not data:
                break

            # add the data to the command
            command += data

            # check whether the command is complete or not
            if command.endswith("\n"):
                complete_command = True
                command = command.rstrip('\r\n')

            if complete_command:
                # full command entered
                if command == 'IP':
                    # client wants his ip address
                    client_ip, client_port = client_address_input
                    connection_input.send(client_ip)

                elif command == 'TIME':
                    # client wants the server-time
                    connection_input.send(time.ctime())

                elif command == 'EXIT':
                    # stop the program
                    connection_input.close()
                    s.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
                    s.close()

                else:
                    # command is not supported
                    connection_input.send("The command you've entered is not supported")

                complete_command = False
                command = ""

try:
    while True:
        # wait for a connection
        connection, client_address = s.accept()

        # start a thread to handle the client
        t = Thread(target=handle_client, args=(connection, client_address))
        t.start()

finally:
    connection.close()
```

Comment: Use `s.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)` instead of `s.close()`. Note that this will make `s.accept()` throw an exception, which you probably want to catch.

Comment: I've tried that but the server still won't shut down, I just get an attribute error every single time.

Comment: What is attribute error specifically? Your edit just seemed to remove a traceback from the original question; it didn't add any new information.

Comment: I see I've messed up the edit. Sorry about that. Should be fine now

Comment: You're masking the `socket` module with a variable named `socket`. Your original code didn't do this - you used the variable `s` instead. Just revert back to using `s` and it will work fine.

Comment: Thanks for that. However, it still didn't solve my problem, I'm still getting an error and the program doesn't shut down. Hopefully I've edited my code and error correct this time.

Comment: I don't have a Mac to test this on, but according to [this](https://github.com/Petteri/telepaatti/commit/eae8112f1467b92b0b17f6aa68361eb6492a563c), you can handle it by catching that exception and then calling `close()`.

Comment: I don't see how that would help. The socket.error will always be thrown and it will just always call close(), which didn't work and that's the reason I asked this question in the first place. No problem if you can't help me, but can you unmark this question as duplicate?

Comment: I've re-opened it. There may be a way to get it working on OS X, but as I mentioned I don't have an OS X machine to test anything with.

Comment: If my problem is OS X related, I'll close this question. It's good enough if it works on windows.

Comment: My problem is not OS X related, just tried it on my windows machine.

Comment: Hmm, apparently using `shutdown` only works on Linux, then. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit of a hack, but you could make a local connection to the server just before calling `s.close()`, which will guarantee `s.accept()` immediately raises an exception:

```
def handle_client(connection_input, client_address_input):
    """ Will handle the requests of the client
    :param connection_input: Connection with the client
    :param client_address_input: Address of the client
    :return: No return value
    """
    <snip>
    while True:
        <snip>

                elif command == 'EXIT':

                    connection_input.close()
                    # Make a local connection, then close the socket
                    socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM).connect((TCP_HOST, TCP_PORT))
                    s.close()
                    break # Break out of the while loop here.


try:
    while True:
        # this will never block, because of select.select
        connection, client_address = s.accept()

        # start a thread to handle the client
        t = Thread(target=handle_client, args=(connection, client_address))
        t.start()
except socket.error:
    print("Shutting down")

finally:
    connection.close()
```

Comment: Yes, I know how to use the select module to handle multiple clients. But select is only semi-concurrent and my task specifically stated that I have to use the thread module. Sorry if it wasn't clear from my question, I've changed it now. I really do appreciate your effort though.

Comment: This solution still uses threads for each connection, though. The only difference is it uses `select` so that you don't block forever on `s.accept()`.

Comment: We were specifically told to write 2 scripts, one uses the threading module, the other uses select.

Comment: @ThomasVanhelden I've edited my answer to do it without using `select`.